# How to create a compact comparison table like this?

Tags: tables

How do you create a comparison table like this?

[image]

In particular, the slanted labels that save space, and the circles / half-filled circles. These kinds of tables seem fairly common --- is there a special package for creating tables like this?

Also, I think there already is a question about exactly the same kind of table, but unfortunately it had a title as vague as this one, so I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: and what you try so far? questions "do-it-for-me" is not likely to be answered here. see, if package `makecell` can help you to type slanted text.

Comment: There's no dedicated package, as far as I know, but a number of packages that will let you build such tables: `makecell`, mentioned by @Zarko,  `array`, `rotating`, `booktabs`, `threeparttable` and `wasy` for the half-filled bullets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a partial reconstruction of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\hbox to1em{\hss\rotatebox[origin=br]{-60}{#1}}}
\newcommand*\feature[1]{\ifcase#1 -\or\LEFTcircle\or\CIRCLE\fi}
\newcommand*\f[3]{\feature#1&\feature#2&\feature#3}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ex[9]{#1\tnote{#2}&#3&%
    \f#4&\f#5&\f#6&\f#7&\f#8&\f#9&\expandafter\f\@firstofone
}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{G}{c@{}c@{}c}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table caption here}
\label{tab:features}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lc GG !{\kern1em} GGG !{\kern1em} GG@{}}
\toprule
Scheme  & Example & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Security Features} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Usability} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Adoption}\\
\midrule
% rotated items
&& \rot{Network MitM Prevented}
 & \rot{Operator MitM Prevented}
 & \rot{Operator MitM Detected}
 %
 & \rot{Operator Accountability}
 & \rot{Key Revocation Possible}
 & \rot{Privacy Preserving}
 %
 & \rot{Automatic Key Initialization}
 & \rot{Low Key Maintenance}
 & \rot{Easy Key Discovery}
 %
 & \rot{Easy Key Recover}
 & \rot{In-Band}
 & \rot{No Shared Secrets}
 %
 & \rot{Alert-less Key Renewal}
 & \rot{Immediate Enrollment}
 & \rot{Inattentive User Resistant}
 %
 & \rot{Multiple Key Support}
 & \rot{No Service Provider}
 & \rot{No Auditing Required}
 %
 & \rot{No Name Squatting}
 & \rot{Asynchronous}
 & \rot{Scalable}\\
\midrule
\ex{Opportunistic Encryption}{\dag*}{TCPCrypt}            {000}{002} {222}{222}{222} {222}{222}\\
\ex{+TOFU (Strict)}{\dag}{-}                              {111}{102} {222}{022}{022} {022}{222}\\
\ex{+TOFU}{\dag*}{TextSecure}                             {111}{102} {222}{222}{020} {022}{222}\\
\midrule
\ex{Key Fringerprint Verification}{\dag*}{Threema}        {222}{212} {000}{002}{000} {022}{222}\\
\ex{+Short Auth Strings (Out-of-Band}{\dag*}{SilentText}  {222}{212} {000}{002}{000} {002}{202}\\
\ex{+Short Auth Strings (In-Band/Voice/Video}{\dag*}{ZRTP}{222}{212} {000}{012}{000} {022}{202}\\
\ex{+Socialist Millionaire (SMP)}{\dag*}{OTR}             {222}{212} {000}{020}{000} {022}{202}\\
\ex{+Mandatory Verification}{\dag*}{SafeSlinger}          {222}{212} {000}{020}{022} {022}{202}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item \hfil$\feature2=\text{provides property}$; $\feature1=\text{partially provides property}$;
$\text{\feature0}=\text{does not provide property}$;
\item \hfil\textsuperscript{\dag}has academic publication;
\textsuperscript{*}end-user tool available
\end{tablenotes}    \end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

See~\ref{tab:features}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments.

1. I defined `\rot` to handle rotating the slanted labels. It uses `\rotatebox[origin=br]{-60}` to rotate the label -60 degrees about the bottom right corner. That is placed inside an `\hbox` that's `1em` wide with infinite shrinkability on the left so that the label protrudes out the left side of the box.
2. I didn't want to type `\LEFTcircle` and `\CIRCLE` from the `wasysym` package over and over, so I defined `\feature` which takes a single argument (in this case, 0, 1, or 2) and produces the appropriate symbol. (Based on the footnotes, I probably should have called it `\property` instead.)
3. The main part of the table is grouped into groups of 3 which are themselves grouped into 2 or 3 groups of 3. Using the `array` package, I created a new column type `G` (for group) that corresponds to three centered columns with no intercolumn space. I also defined `\f` which takes three digits and produces the three features (properties) for a group. (I probably should have gone with `\g` to stick with group rather than `\f` for features.)
4. To get extra space between the groups of groups, I used the `array` specifier `!` to insert an extra `\kern1em` between those columns.
5. Each row logically consists of 10 parts: the scheme, the table note symbols, the example, and seven groups of 3. TeX only supports macros with up to 9 arguments, so when I created `\ex` (which was to stand for example, but on reflection, something related to scheme would have been better) which takes 9 arguments. The first 3 correspond to the scheme, marks, and example. The remaining 6 expect 3 digits to pass to `\f`. Finally, the 10th braced group is unbraced using `\@firstofone` and then passed to `\f`. I admit, that's kind of a hack, but it makes using `\ex` easier.
6. `threeparttable` consists of a caption, the tabular, and the tablenotes below.
7. The tabular itself is pretty straight-forward. I've used `booktabs`'s `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` to typeset the horizontal rules. (This looks much better than `\hline`.)
8. The table notes are centered in your example. I had to work a little bit to get that here. In particular, I added some `\hfil`s. I think it would look better to not center the notes.
9. `Scheme` is indented slightly for some reason in your example. I didn't understand the point of that, so I didn't do it. Adding `\quad` (or some other horizontal spacing command) could reproduce that.
10. If I were creating this table, I would typeset the "Example" column left-aligned. I might also replace the `-` in that column with `None` or maybe just leave it blank. I'd probably also replace the `-` in the main columns with an en dash. I just think it looks better. Conveniently, you only have to replace `-` with `--` in `\feature` to change it everywhere, including the table notes.

Some metacomments.

1. To find individual symbols, you should look in the `symbols-a4` document (run `texdoc symbols-a4`).
2. Generally speaking, asking TeX SX to reproduce some particular image doesn't work out too well. (I was just curious to learn about `threeparttable` which I'd never used before so I took a stab at it.) Posting a minimal example demonstrating what you've tried and asking about particular elements you are stuck on works best. E.g., "How do I rotate the text in a cell of a table?"