# Unable to align comparison table properly

Tags: tables, tabularx, overleaf, threeparttable

im quite new to latex and try to create a comparison table based on this one:
[How to create a compact comparison table like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377638/how-to-create-a-compact-comparison-table-like-this)
I managed to configure everything for my needs but i have problems with the proper allignment of everything.
Right now the column don't align with the same space next to each other.

```
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\hbox to2em{\hss\rotatebox[origin=br]{-40}{#1}}}
\newcommand*\feature[1]{\ifcase#1 -\or\LEFTcircle\or\CIRCLE\fi}
\newcommand*\f[3]{\feature#1&\feature#2&\feature#3}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ex[5]{#1&#2&%
    \f#3&\f#4&\f#5
}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{G}{c@{}c@{}c}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table caption here}
\label{tab:features}
\begin{tabular}{lc G !{\kern4em} G !{\kern4em} G}
\toprule
Tool & Type & \multicolumn{3}{c}{DevOps} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Project} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Security and Compliance}\\
\midrule
% rotated items
&& \rot{State Management}
 & \rot{DevOps processes support}
 & \rot{Modularity support}
 %
 & \rot{Azure and GitLab support}
 & \rot{VM configuration}
 & \rot{Idempotency}
 %
 & \rot{Error handling}
 & \rot{Free and open source}
 & \rot{Naming and safety rules}\\
\midrule
\ex{Terraform}{(Declarative)}     {222}   {222}   {222}\\
\midrule
\ex{Azure Biceps}{(Declarative)}  {222}   {222}   {222}\\
\midrule
\ex{Ansible}{(Imperative)}        {222}   {222}   {222}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item \hfil$\feature2=\text{provides property}$; $\feature1=\text{partially provides property}$;
$\text{\feature0}=\text{does not provide property}$;
\item \hfil\textsuperscript{\dag}has academic publication;
\textsuperscript{*}end-user tool available
\end{tablenotes}    
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

[image: Comparison Table]

Comment: If you want people to help you please provide a proper minimal example not a sniplet like this that people cannot test without adding code. Additionally please don't expect others to know what you mean by `I managed to configure everything for my needs but i have problems with the proper allignment of everything. Right now the column don't align with the same space next to each other`